# Getting the first available null value in an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a small volunteering system that I am working on and in my volunteering table, I have 2 columns where users can volunteer to take part in an event.

The table looks like so:

```
id event_name user_1 user_2 created_at
```

What I would like to achieve is when a user volunteers for an event, the next available user slot is given to him.  Ie, if `user_1` and `user_2` have no values, and the user volunteers, assign the first available slot to him (`user_1`) and `user_id` is not null, save the user id in the `user_2` column.

I have ran a query to return the `user_1` and `user_2` columns based on the event id.  Problem I am having is writing the PHP code to select the first available empty array item so i can save the user id?

Hope I am sort of making sense..

Thanks

Comment: Post your table schema with expected results

Comment: Events Table Schema
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    event_name VARCHAR(50)
    user_1 INT(11) NOT NULL
    user_2 INT(11) NOT NULL
    created_at DATETIME

Comment: Yes.. events table schema

Comment: At least give some pseudocode of what you are trying to achieve. It is not making much sense as it is.

Comment: what if a third user tries to volunteer?

Comment: this is what I am trying to achieve:

first select the the 2 columns from the events table: 
`select user_1, user_2 from events where id = 1`

in php, if user_1 and user_2 are both null, select the first item in the array (user_1) and save the user id into the user_1 column.  if user_1 column is not empty save user id into user_2 column and vice versa.

if the both columns (user_1 and user_2) are not empty, do not allow any more volunteering.

(trying to get to grips with this markdown thing.. my apologies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off normalising that table, into an events table, and an event_volunteers table.

`event(id, name, max_volunteers)`

`event_volunteers(event_id, user_id)`

Then you don't have to worry about which field is null or not, and you don't limit yourself to two volunteers per event - ie, more flexibility.

Instead, you can check if an event is 'open' to volunteers by comparing the count of event_volunteers to the `max_volunteers` field like so.

```
select e.id, e.name
  from event e
    left join event_volunteers ev
      on e.id = ev.event_id
  group by e.id
  having count(ev.event_id) < e.max_volunteers
```

With a `left join`, it will return `null` values for all the fields of `event_volunteers` if there are no volunteers for the particular `event`.  `count()` ignores `null` values, so even tho there is a row there to count, the count will be `0`.

You can limit this to check a specific event by introducing a `where` clause.

And to assign a volunteer to an event, you just insert their `user_id` into the `event_volunteers` table.

You could then pull a list of all of your volunteers by performing the above query, but without the `group by` or `having clause`, eg:

```
select e.id, e.name, ev.user_id
  from event e
    inner join event_volunteers ev
      on e.id = ev.event_id
```

This will only show events for which there are least one volunteer (because of the `inner join`). Should you wish to show all events, with volunteers (if any). change the `inner join` to a `left join`, and you will get `null` values in `ev.user_id` if there are no volunteers for that event.